# sort array of array number of string with dot sparator

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of an array that has value like this:

```
arr = [
  ['1','lorem'],
  ['2','ipsum'],
  ['1.1','sit'],
  ['1.2','lorem'],
  ['3','ipsum'],
  ['1.3','sit'],
  ['1.4','sit'],
  ['1.5','lorem'],
  ['4','ipsum'],
  ['1.6','sit'],
  ['1.7','sit'],
  ['1.8','sit'],
  ['1.9','lorem'],
  ['5','ipsum'],
  ['1.10','sit']
]
```

sorting into like this:

```
arr = [
  ['1','lorem'],
  ['1.1','sit'],
  ['1.2','lorem'],
  ['1.3','sit'],
  ['1.4','sit'],
  ['1.5','lorem'],
  ['1.6','sit'],
  ['1.7','sit'],
  ['1.8','sit'],
  ['1.9','lorem'],
  ['1.10','sit']
  ['2','ipsum'],
  ['3','ipsum'],
  ['4','ipsum'],
  ['5','ipsum'],

]
```

I already sort using localCompare but actually it is not valid sort because of 1.10 value is list before 1.2 or 1.3. That I need is 1.2 is sort before 1.10 or 1.11 and so on.

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the *numeric* option of [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters)

> **`numeric`**
>   Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`.

```js
const arr = [
  ['1','lorem'],
  ['2','ipsum'],
  ['1.1','sit'],
  ['1.2','lorem'],
  ['3','ipsum'],
  ['1.3','sit'],
  ['1.4','sit'],
  ['1.5','lorem'],
  ['4','ipsum'],
  ['1.6','sit'],
  ['1.7','sit'],
  ['1.8','sit'],
  ['1.9','lorem'],
  ['5','ipsum'],
  ['1.10','sit']
]

arr.sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }))

console.info(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string based on '.' and then compare each part separately as below -

```
var arr = [
  ['1','lorem'],
  ['2','ipsum'],
  ['1.1','sit'],
  ['1.2','lorem'],
  ['3','ipsum'],
  ['1.3','sit'],
  ['1.4','sit'],
  ['1.5','lorem'],
  ['4','ipsum'],
  ['1.6','sit'],
  ['1.7','sit'],
  ['1.8','sit'],
  ['1.9','lorem'],
  ['5','ipsum'],
  ['1.10','sit']
]

var sortedArr=arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  var aArr=a[0].split('.');
  var bArr=b[0].split('.');
  if(aArr[0]!==bArr[0]) {
    return aArr[0]-bArr[0];
  }
  else {
    if(aArr.length===1) {
      return -1
    }
    if(bArr.length===1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return parseInt(aArr[1])-parseInt(bArr[1]);
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedArr));
// [["1","lorem"],["1.1","sit"],["1.2","lorem"],["1.3","sit"],["1.4","sit"],["1.5","lorem"],["1.6","sit"],["1.7","sit"],["1.8","sit"],["1.9","lorem"],["1.10","sit"],["2","ipsum"],["3","ipsum"],["4","ipsum"],["5","ipsum"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom comparator

```js
function sorta(a, b) {
    let [numA, decA] = a[0].split(".");
    let [numB, decB] = b[0].split(".");
 if (numA != numB) {
  return numA - numB;     
 } else {
  return decA-decB
    }
} 

arr = [
  ['1','lorem'],
  ['2','ipsum'],
  ['1.1','sit'],
  ['1.2','lorem'],
  ['3','ipsum'],
  ['1.3','sit'],
  ['1.4','sit'],
  ['1.5','lorem'],
  ['4','ipsum'],
  ['1.6','sit'],
  ['1.7','sit'],
  ['1.8','sit'],
  ['1.9','lorem'],
  ['5','ipsum'],
  ['1.10','sit']
]

console.log(arr.sort(sorta))
```